# Web API - How to upload excel file with request parameters using Fiddler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am uploading excel file on server through Web Api. I need to pass some parameters along with the file.

But when I am using fiddler i can able to  get either Request parameters or file only, but i need both things in my web API controller.

Method Type: Post
URL : http://localhost/MP.Services/api/catalog/file/upload/

Request Header-

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 74
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf

Request Body-
{
"CatalogCode":"1",
"Action":"1",
"Entity":"1",
"UploadedBy":"1"
}

Above is my Normal way to pass request parameter, I tried to upload the excel file in fiddler from 'Upload file' option along with above request, but when file gets uploaded request header and request body gets change. 
When I run this then I will not able to get the Request Parameters to my web API controller.

My Controller Action Code-

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadCatalogExcel(CatalogUploadRequest catalogUploadRequest)
        {
            if (catalogUploadRequest == null)
                return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ControllerErrorCodeConstants.RequestIsInvalid, "Invalid request");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);

            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "Uploading file is mandatory");

            try
            {
                //Request to BL Mapping

                var catalogUploadExcelBi = CatalogUploadMapping.UploadCatalogExcelRequestToBiMap(catalogUploadRequest);

                var CatalogInfo = _catalogUploadBi.GetSampleCatalogExcel(catalogUploadExcelBi.CatalogCode);

                string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
                uploadPath = uploadPath + "\\Upload\\" + CatalogInfo.SellerAccountId + "_" + CatalogInfo.SellerAccountName + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_" + CatalogInfo.CatalogCode; // Physical File Location

                string currentTime = Regex.Replace(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "[^0-9]+", "");
                string name = catalogUploadExcelBi.CatalogCode + "_" + currentTime + ".xlsx"; // File Name                              

                catalogUploadExcelBi.FileName = "aa";
                catalogUploadExcelBi.FilePath = uploadPath;                            

                bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(uploadPath);
                if (!exists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);

                MyStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyStreamProvider(uploadPath);
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);   

                var response = _catalogUploadBi.LogUploadCatalogExcel(catalogUploadExcelBi);

                if (response.ServerErrors != null && response.ServerErrors.Count != 0)
                {
                    response.ServerErrors = response.ServerErrors;
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.ServerErrors);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "File uploaded successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = _errorManager.GetCustomeError(ex.GetType().ToString());

                return error != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error.ErrorCode) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error.ErrorMessage)
                    ? Request.CreateResponse(string.Format("Exception Occured! Error code : {0}  Error Message :   {1}", error.ErrorCode,
                        error.ErrorMessage)) : Request.CreateResponse(string.Format("Upload file method Exception Occured!"));
            }           
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller signature, and what the parameters / body are when you upload?

Comment: Is anybody know the solution for this problem... Thanks in advance.